Why is animateinline stretching my text, and how can I stop it?
I'm new to animate, and was pleasantly surprised to see that I could simultaneously animate a set of images and a label to go with them.  However when the label changes length, it gets stretched to what looks like the bounding box of the first label:
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{animate}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Raster tools}{GIMP, ImageJ}
    \begin{animateinline}[loop,autoplay]{1}
        Source figures (photo, data)%
        \newframe
        Colourise *%
        \newframe
        Paste over top of photo as a new layer%
        \newframe
        Paste over top of photo as a new layer%
        \newframe
        Colour to alpha (transparency)%
        \newframe
        Done%
    \end{animateinline}
\end{frame}
\end{document}


While this example uses Okular as a viewer (the best/only option for animated PDFs on Linux) if I use the [export] option for animate, combined with \documentclass{standalone} I get the same effect but on separate pages in Atril, Inkscape, and GIMP.
So am I doing something wrong in this almost trivial use case? Is it a bug - I doubt it becxause surely this is a common way to use animateinline? How do I work around it?

The size of the first frame determines the size of the whole animation. All following frames are squeezed or stretched to fit into this box. To avoid undesired scaling effects, put every frame text into \makebox[l][<width>]{\strut ...} and adjust <width> to the length of the longest text.

@AlexG I was thinking along similar lines, though hadn't got as far as testing it (I've been upgrading to the latest TeX Live, which meant clearing disc space); what surprises me is that the standard behaviour is something that's going to be undesirable in so many cases

... (@AlexG) minor correction - it's \makebox[<width>][<position>]{\strut ...} (not [<position>][<width>].  The full solution here has \usepackage{calc} and\makebox[\widthof{<widest frame text>}][l]{\strut <frame text>.  Would you like to write (or start; I can fill in details) an answer so you get the votes?

Thanks, I was in doubt as well about the correct options order. Go ahead and write an answer, I am on holidays :)

Based on ChrisH's answer, one can avoid code duplication by means of animateinline's begin and end options:
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{animate}
\usepackage{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Raster tools}{GIMP, ImageJ}
  \begin{animateinline}[
    loop,autoplay,
    begin={\begin{lrbox}{0}},
    end={\end{lrbox}\makebox[\widthof{Paste over top of photo as a new layer}][l]{\strut\usebox{0}}}
  ]{1}
    Source figures (photo, data)
  \newframe
    Colourise *
  \newframe
    Paste over top of photo as a new layer
  \newframe
    Colour to alpha (transparency)
  \newframe
    Done
  \end{animateinline}
\end{frame}
\end{document}


I knew there should be a way to automate at least some of it, but had no idea where to start.  Thanks

The solution (thanks to AlexG, who now has a more complete answer) is to wrap each piece of text in a box the size of the longest piece.  So \makebox[<width>][<position>]{\strut ...}.  Thisis easiest with the use of the calc package, which allows \makebox[\widthof{<widest frame text>}][l]{\strut <frame text>.
In full, my example becomes
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{animate}
\usepackage{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Raster tools}{GIMP, ImageJ}
    \begin{animateinline}[loop,autoplay]{1}
        \makebox[\widthof{Paste over top of photo as a new layer}][l]{\strut Source figures (photo, data)}%
        \newframe
        \makebox[\widthof{Paste over top of photo as a new layer}][l]{\strut Colourise *}%
        \newframe
        \makebox[\widthof{Paste over top of photo as a new layer}][l]{\strut Paste over top of photo as a new layer}%
        \newframe
        \makebox[\widthof{Paste over top of photo as a new layer}][l]{\strut Colour to alpha (transparency)}%
        \newframe
        \makebox[\widthof{Paste over top of photo as a new layer}][l]{\strut Done}%
    \end{animateinline}
\end{frame}
\end{document}


